# Initializing a variable in MIPS

Tags: variables, initialization, mips

What's the difference between the following two ways of initializing a variable?

```
addi $a0, $0, 7

li $a0, 7
```

Comment: Instruction side effects aside, the addi version will require a bit more ram to store 2 immediate values, compared to one for the li.

Comment: Registers, not RAM, and $0 is fixed

Comment: @Marc B: nonsense, neither instruction involves RAM and all MISP instructions are fixed 32-bits (RISC stuff here). ADDI is preferred because it's one instruction while LI is a pseudo-instruction and expands into 2 real instructions.

Answer (score 1):

None really, li is generally implemented in hardware as an addi.

Comment: How come if I try to initialize with li it complains that the variable was not initialized? And how come if the variable is given a value before li, the assembler doesn't complain, but it interprets it as adding a number to it's original value?

Comment: What emulator/assembler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

ADDI is preferred because it's one instruction while LI is a pseudo-instruction and expands into 2 real instructions.